# Linked List Implementation in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I came across a sample program that adds numbers to linked list

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Node {
    public int data;
    public Node next;
    Node(int d){
        data=d;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkList f1 = new LinkList();
        for(int j=0;j<=10;j++){
        f1.inject(j);
        }
        f1.display();
    }

}
class LinkList {
    Node firstlink;
    LinkList(){
        firstlink=null;
    }
    void inject(int a){
     Node pw=new Node(a);
        pw.next=firstlink;
        firstlink=pw;
    }
    void display(){
       Node pw=firstlink;
        while(pw !=null){
            System.out.println(pw.data);
            pw=pw.next;
        }
    }

}
```

I have some doubt regarding how it's implemented here .
first how does

```
Node pw=new Node(a);
        pw.next=firstlink;
        firstlink=pw;
```

adds item to linked list ?
and why statement

```
Node pw=firstlink;
```

what does it do ?

and how will we delete item from linked list?

Comment: Well the last one is easy, you can't unless you add your own method. Meaning that this code, in it's entirely, will not be able to delete items from the list.

Comment: You "came across this code" ... like, in your homework assignment?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list pretty much covers anything you'd ever want to know about linked lists.

Comment: @BrianRoach on a website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Injecting element to LinkedList?
```

The way it is done is every time inject is called new Node is created with the provided integer value.

```
Node pw=new Node(a);
```

This newly create Node instance is made to point to the current Head Node

```
pw.next=firstlink;
```

and then then the new instance created is made the new Node.

```
firstlink=pw;
```

As you know in LinkedList all we have to do is maintain the Head Node. To iterate we simply call `next()` till `!= null`. In the sample code `firstlink` represents the Head Node.

Comment: um , can you elaborate in easy way ?

Comment: ok then how will last pointer be null , i do not how last pointer should be null in this example ?

Comment: It was `null` when the list was first created because when it was created it didn't have any data, and therefore couldn't save anything else in it's place. I'm not saying that I agree with the way it was done, but that's how it was done.

Comment: how shall I delete last Item i wrote this but this is not working ?
 void remfirst(){
        Node x=firstlink;
        while(firstlink != null){
        if(firstlink.next == null){
            firstlink=null;
        }
            firstlink=firstlink.next;
        }

    }

Comment: Do not increment the header pointer. You can increment your **Node x** pointer and if `x.next.next == null` you can do `x.next = null`